# Post image is no more working with new iOS Facebook SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios7

I add the function working well on iOS6, but with iOS7, I had to update Facebook SDK because id and setId from the old ones are marked as non-public and are'nt validated.
So, I replaced the old SDK by the new one but, of course, the post image is no more working (as the id is certainly unknown).
I had this :

```
[params setObject:textViewMessageFacebook.text forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenshot) forKey:@"picture"];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos", idAmiS]
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error)
```

but don't know how to correct it to have it working... 
Thanks

Comment: use SlCompser controller...

Comment: Can you check your permissions array part, Is that all well ?

Answer (score 0):

Use SlComposer Controller to post image on facebook.

1) first you add the Social framework and Account framewok into your project and then try below code

writ this code where you want...

```
    {
    ACAccountType *facebookTypeAccount = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];


        [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookTypeAccount
                                               options:@{ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"131740927031850", ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"email"]}
                                            completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                                if(granted){
                                                    NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookTypeAccount];
                                                    _facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
                                                    ACAccountCredential *fbCredential = [_facebookAccount credential];
                                                    accessToken = [fbCredential oauthToken];
                                                    NSLog(@"Facebook Access Token: %@", accessToken);
                                                    NSLog(@"Success");

                                                    [self facebook];
                                                }else{
                                                    NSLog(@"Fail");
                                                    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                                }
                                            }];

        if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
        {
            SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
            [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"posting from my own app! :)"];
            [tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.xyz.com"]];


// Here you add the image

             [tweetSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];




            [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];


        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                      initWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                                      message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one Twitter account setup"
                                      delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }


    }



    - (void)facebook
    {

        NSURL *meurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];
        NSLog(@"URl:-%@",meurl);
        SLRequest *merequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                  requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                            URL:meurl
                                                     parameters:nil];

        merequest.account = _facebookAccount;

        [merequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
            NSString *meDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSLog(@"Parsed Data:-%@", meDataString);

        }];

    }
```